# Escape special character ^ in a regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a string in Java with the following format:
"value^1" so that I get the initial part, "value" in a string.

I wanted to use split instead of substring, so I tried this:

```
string.split("^")[0]
```

but unfortunately ^ is a special character and I guess it has to be escaped. I tried split("\^") but no luck.

Anybody knows how to achieve this using split?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to escape the `^` in the regex but you also need to escape the `\` in the String with `\` so you end up with `\\^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the escape: `split("\\^")`. Or `split(Pattern.quote("^"))`.

But since you only want the first part of it, there's no need to use `split`:

```
int pos = string.indexOf('^');
String firstPart = (pos != -1) ? string.substring(0, pos) : string;
```